# How to structure the fields added to logstash events?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

In Logstash I'm currently using `grok` to parse log lines into events with a flat structure.

For example:

```
{
location_file_name: "ServiceDao.java"
location_line_number: 47
thread_name: "main-thread"
thread_number: "3"
}
```

How can I instead parse it into:

```
{
location : {
    file: "ServiceDao"
    line: 47
}
thread : {
    name: "main-thread"
    number: "3"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grokking your data you can reorganize your fields as you see fit using the `mutate` filter like this:

```
filter {
    grok {
       ...
    }
    mutate {
       add_field => {
           "[location][file]" => "%{location_file_name}"
           "[location][line]" => "%{location_line_number}"
           "[thread][name]" => "%{thread_name}"
           "[thread][number]" => "%{thread_number}"
       }
       remove_field => ["location_file_name", "location_line_number", "thread_name", "thread_number"]
    }
}
```